# Laravel reverse query data from child to get parent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 table called `defects` and `defect_types` and `defect_types` is the child of `defects`

Now I wanted to query the `defect_types` by `project_id` but `project_id` is not in `defect_types` instead is in `defect_types` parent which is `defects`. I couldn't get it right and below is my code :

Controller :

```
class ProjectDashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxGetDefectTypes($proj_id)
    {
        $defectTypes = DefectType::with('defect')
            ->whereHas('defects', function ($query) {$query->where('project_id', $proj_id);})
            ->get();
        return $defectTypes;
    }
}
```

Model :

```
class DefectType extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = ['title','details','created_by','is_custom','developer_id'];

    public function defects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Defect', 'defect_type_id');
    }
}
```

JS :

```
getDefectTypes(function (results) {
    console.log(results)
})


// SECTION: API
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

function getDefectTypes(onSuccess) {
    var getDefectTypesRoute = "{{ route('dev-admin.projects.dashboard.defect-types.ajax.get', ['proj_id' => $proj_id ]) }}";
    $.ajax({
        url: getDefectTypesRoute,
        type: 'GET',
        data: data = {
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    },
        success: function(projects) {
            onSuccess(projects)
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            if(xhr.status == 422) {
                var errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                console.log("Error 422: ", xhr);
            }
            console.log("Error: ", xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is issue ?

Comment: The issue is in your code, you have defined `defects` as your relation and calling `defect` in your code `with('defect')`

Comment: what is the field name in defect_types & defects table ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

Controller :

```
class ProjectDashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxGetDefectTypes($proj_id)
    {
        $defectTypes = DefectType::with('defect')
            ->whereHas('defects', function ($query) use ($proj_id){
                $query->where('project_id', $proj_id);
            })
            ->get();
        return $defectTypes;
    }
}
```

Model :

```
class DefectType extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = ['title','details','created_by','is_custom','developer_id'];

    public function defects()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Defect');
    }
}
```

JS :

```
getDefectTypes(function (results) {
    console.log(results)
})


// SECTION: API
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

function getDefectTypes(onSuccess) {
    var getDefectTypesRoute = "{{ route('dev-admin.projects.dashboard.defect-types.ajax.get', ['proj_id' => $proj_id ]) }}";
    $.ajax({
        url: getDefectTypesRoute,
        type: 'GET',
        data: data = {
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
    },
        success: function(projects) {
            onSuccess(projects)
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            if(xhr.status == 422) {
                var errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                console.log("Error 422: ", xhr);
            }
            console.log("Error: ", xhr);
        }
    });
}
```